# How to replace SQLite database on running application

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dropdown

I am new to Android. I have an app which contains two dropdown lists whose values I am taking from a SQLite database.

Now I have a button. After clicking it, I want to replace the values of the dropdown lists.

For example, if I had {A,B,C,D} in the dropdown from SQLite DB #1,
after clicking the button, I want {Q,W,E,R} from SQLite DB #2.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: yes, it is possible, can you edit your question, show us more about your Code on how you implement the dropdownlist or any code that may help us understand more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you simply want to switch the dropdown lists then this could be done two ways; You can :-

a) swap the source data for the adapters or
b) swap the views adapters.

The following is an example that includes both, utilising two databases with identical tables (which appears to match the scenario you have described).

### First the layout

- One TextView, to describe which adapter and database is used)
- Two spinners
- two Buttons (one for each method)

#### activity_main.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ddse.dropdownswitchexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dropdown1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dropdown2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switchbyadpater"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch by Adapter"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switchbyswapcursor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch by Cursor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### The DatabaseHelper for Database 1

#### DBHelper1.java

```
public class DBHelper1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB1NAME = "db1";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBNAME = "dropdowns";
    public static final String DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM = "item";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper1(Context context) {
        super(context, DB1NAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME +
                "(" +
                DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM + " TEXT " +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insertDropDownItem(String item) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM,item);
        return mDB.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllDropDownItems() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id,*"};
        return mDB.query(TBNAME, columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

### The DatabaseHelper for Database 2

#### DBHelper2.java

```
public class DBHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB2NAME = "db2";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBNAME = "dropdowns";
    public static final String DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM = "item";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;


    public DBHelper2(Context context) {
        super(context, DB2NAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME +
                "(" +
                DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM + " TEXT " +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insertDropDownItem(String item) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM,item);
        return mDB.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllDropDownItems() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id,*"};
        return mDB.query(TBNAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- **Note** the code could easily be reduced/combined as there is hardly any difference between the two database helpers.

### The Main/Invoking Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Define View related class variables    
    TextView mTitle;
    Spinner mSpinner1, mSpinner2;
    Button mSwapByAdapter, mSwapByCursor;
    boolean spinner1_using_adapter1_state = true;
    boolean adapter1_using_db1_state = true;

    // define DB related class variables
    DBHelper1 mDB1hlpr;
    DBHelper2 mDB2hlpr;
    Cursor mCsr1, mCsr2;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA1, mSCA2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Set View related variables    
        mTitle = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mSpinner1 = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.dropdown1);
        mSpinner2 = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.dropdown2);
        mSwapByAdapter = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.switchbyadpater);
        mSwapByCursor = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.switchbyswapcursor);

        / Set DB helpers
        mDB1hlpr = new DBHelper1(this);
        mDB2hlpr = new DBHelper2(this);

        loadSomeItems(); // Load data for spinners
        refreshSpinners(); refresh spinners (sets them up)

        // Set button Listeners
        mSwapByAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                spinner1_using_adapter1_state = !spinner1_using_adapter1_state; // Switch Adapters used by Spinners
                refreshSpinners();
            }
        });
        mSwapByCursor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter1_using_db1_state = !adapter1_using_db1_state; // Switch Cursor used by adapters
                refreshSpinners();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCsr1.close();
        mCsr2.close();
    }

    // Load data for spinners if none loaded    
    private void loadSomeItems() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB1hlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DBHelper1.TBNAME) < 1) {
            mDB1hlpr.insertDropDownItem("A");
            mDB1hlpr.insertDropDownItem("B");
            mDB1hlpr.insertDropDownItem("C");
            mDB1hlpr.insertDropDownItem("D");
        }

        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB2hlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DBHelper2.TBNAME) < 1) {
            mDB2hlpr.insertDropDownItem("Q");
            mDB2hlpr.insertDropDownItem("W");
            mDB2hlpr.insertDropDownItem("E");
            mDB2hlpr.insertDropDownItem("R");
        }
    }

    // resfresh the spinners according to the 2 states    
    private void refreshSpinners() {

        // re-get the underlying data
        mCsr1 = mDB1hlpr.getAllDropDownItems();
        mCsr2 = mDB2hlpr.getAllDropDownItems();
        // Prepare for reporting on what is using what
        String adapter1_source = "";
        String adapter2_source = "";
        String spinner1_using = "";
        String spinner2_using = "";

        // If adapter 1 should be using DB1 then
        //     set adapter 1 to use csr from DB1 and 
        //     set adpater 2 to use csr from DB 2    
        if (adapter1_using_db1_state) {
            adapter1_source = "Database 1 ";
            adapter2_source = "Database 2 ";
            // If adapter 1 is null then instantiate it
            if (mSCA1 == null) {
                mSCA1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        mCsr1,
                         new String[] {DBHelper1.DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM},
                        new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                        0
                );
            } else {
                // otherwise swap the cursor
                mSCA1.swapCursor(mCsr1);
            }
            / Like adapter 1
            if (mSCA2 == null) {
                mSCA2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        mCsr2,
                        new String[]{DBHelper2.DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM},
                        new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                        0
                );
            } else {
                mSCA2.swapCursor(mCsr2);
            }
        } else {
            // Otherwise Adapter1 uses DB2 and adapter2 uses DB1
            // Very much the same as previously used
            adapter1_source = "Database 2 ";
            adapter2_source = "Database 1 ";
            if (mSCA2 == null) {
                mSCA2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        mCsr1,
                        new String[]{DBHelper1.DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM},
                        new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                        0
                );
            } else {
                mSCA2.swapCursor(mCsr1);
            }
            if (mSCA1 == null) {
                mSCA1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        mCsr2,
                        new String[]{DBHelper2.DROPDOWNS_COL_ITEM},
                        new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                        0
                );
            } else {
                mSCA1.swapCursor(mCsr2);
            }
        }

        // Now consider the Spinner state using the appropriate adpater
        if (spinner1_using_adapter1_state) {
            spinner1_using = "Adapter 1" + adapter1_source;
            spinner2_using = "Adapter 2" + adapter2_source;
            mSpinner1.setAdapter(mSCA1);
            mSpinner2.setAdapter(mSCA2);
        } else {
            spinner1_using = "Adapter 2" + adapter2_source;
            spinner2_using = "Adapter 1" + adapter1_source;
            mSpinner2.setAdapter(mSCA1);
            mSpinner1.setAdapter(mSCA2);
        }
        // Build the title to display what spinner/adapater/DB's are being used.
        StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder();
        title.append("Spinner 1 is using ");
        title.append(spinner1_using);
        title.append(" Spinner 2 is using " + spinner2_using);
        mTitle.setText(title.toString());
    }
}
```

### Resultant App :-

#### When Started :-

[image]

#### Switch by Adapter

[image]

#### Switch By Cursor Swap

[image]

- ***Note*** Look at the top line text to see adapter/DB combinations.